# Move file from outside the runnable .jar into it

Tags: java, jar

I'm writing a quiz, which uses an content.json as source for the question. Now I don't want the user to see this file, because in there are the correct answers. Therefore I created (well not actually me but I changed it for my use-case) a function which reads the content.json which is implemented inside the runnable .jar.

```
public String readFromJARFile(String filename) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    isr.close();
    is.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But now I want my program moving an content.json from outside the .jar document inside it in order to automatically update the content.json inside it.

Is there a way to do that?

Or else is there a nice way to hide the content.json and make it also be automatically update-able by putting a content.json next to the app?

Comment: A .jar is first and foremost an archive that is built on the .zip format. So placing your .json file in the archive does not prevent your user to simply open the archive with their program of choice to extract the file.

Comment: Right, but the users don't see the file next to the runable .jar and for my use-case that's hidden enough, because nobody will look in there

Comment: You can take a look at the [ZipFileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) that enables you to treat a jar as a file system (meaning you can add files in there without manual repacking) but I am quite sure that even with that you won't be able to manipulate the .jar you are currently operating from.

Comment: But that's just a guess I haven't tried it myself so someone else needs to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, that's true you can insert the file manually using 7zip or something else, but the person, which has to update quiz is not experienced, so it would be better to do it automatically.